# Has any Indigo Lantern besides Indigo-1 been redeemed?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Among the various Lantern Corps, the Indigo Tribe wields the indigo light of compassion. Far from all of them being do-gooders, it was revealed some years ago that members of the Tribe were all notoriously criminals, and that the Indigo Lantern ring was forced onto them to make them feel compassion, for them to eventually redeem themselves.

At some point during this arc, the rings went offline and most of the Tribe turned back to their criminal tendencies. Only Indigo-1, the leader, proved to be capable of compassion without her ring, regretting her acts as Iroque, the child killer.

[image: Indigo-1/Iroque cries over the child she murdered, and reignites the Indigo Central Battery]

As far as I know, she was the only one redeemed at that point, and the "indigo rings going offline" stunt hasn't been pulled again since. Still, some years have passed, the Tribe has been subjected to more compassion; is there any indication, in the comics or interviews, that the ring achieved its purpose for other members of the Indigo Tribe? If so, which one(s)?

Of course, that excludes the indigo light wielders such as Kyle Rayner, who are not murderers and truly feel compassion in the first place.

Comment: How would we know? As soon as a user develops compassion the ring can't function properly. Anyone redeemed would be free. Therefore, Indigo-1 was the only person redeemed during the time the rings were "offline." Any other redeemed tribe members would likely have left, given that Indigo rings, like the orange ones, are parasites.

Comment: @GridAlien we might know from writers' interviews stating it, or from, say, Indigo-1 talking about other members of the Tribe, or even future story arcs... Agree to disagree on the "redeemed→free" bit: when Iroque was redeemed, she _chose_ to continue wielding the indigo light, and I'm inclined to think any other "truly compassionate" Lantern would do the same. It's the still guilty who try to leave, as Black Hand did during this arc, killing himself for a Black Ring to take over (instead of staying slave to the Indigo one)